# Cypress test runner crashing issue

Tags: crash, cypress, test-runner

I have only 3 test cases on a spec file -but when i run this spec -cypress runner often crashes chrome browser.
And i have to restart again.
Is this is something with my code ? or is there any solutions for this

Thanks

Comment: Issue is only when i use runner -when i run using command line -all good

Comment: This is the command i am using     ./node_modules/.bin/cypress run -s 'cypress/integration/examples/TestSettingAlert.js'

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the `numTestsKeptInMemory: 5`, the default value might be `50`. This way was can reduce the memory consumption. Save the configuration, close and star the app again.
Avoid writing lengthy tests and split the test file into multiple test/spec files.

Comment: Where should this setting be located? I searched my entire project without finding it.